# matlab convolution operator A and adjoint operator

Tags: matlab, operator-keyword, convolution

I want to calculate the convolution operator A and the adjoint operator AT, i need to calculate AU =H*U, and AT(AU), where H is the kernal and is much small size than the image U. Here is my code, is there any wrong? i don't know how to expand the kernal to the same size as U. Thanks in advance!

---

```
      [M,N] = size(U);
      Mask = zeros(M,N);
      [H1,L] = size(H);
      %Mask([end+1-floor(H1/2):end,1:ceil(H1/2)],[end+1-floor(L/2):end,1:ceil(L/2)]) = H;
      Mask(1:size(h,1),1:size(h,2)) = H;  % here I am not sure!!!!
      FMask=fft2(Mask);
      AU =iff2(FMask.*(fft2(U)))  %%%  AU= H*U 
      ATAU= iff2((abs(FMask).^2).*(fft2(U))) %AT(AU)
```

Comment: any reason not to be using `conv2`?

Comment: @Dan Convolution in the spatial domain is much more computationally expensive than using the fourier convolution theorem.

Comment: @Raab70 but the question makes no mention of computational limitations so before continuing with this approach, it is worthwhile making sure the OP (a) knows about `conv2` and (b) has good reason not to use it.

Comment: Good point. I was simply pointing out one possible reason the OP had chosen to implement this method aside from using `conv2`

Answer (score 0):

"i don't know how to expand the kernal to the same size as U." That's a good question and its most formally known as padding. There are many ways to pad your filter the simplest of course is to just add some zeros around the outside. [This q and a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26432/discrete-fourier-transform-effects-of-zero-padding-compared-to-time-domain-inte) has some information about the effects of zero padding. [This resource](http://hebb.mit.edu/courses/9.29/2002/readings/c13-1.pdf) also has some good information on the effects of padding as well.

Here is a small example that may help:

```
im=imread('peppers.png');
[rows,cols,bands]=size(im);
% //make the meshgrid of coordinates
x=1:cols;y=1:rows;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

% //compute the filter in the fourier domain,
% //centered top right so we dont need to shift
filter = mvnpdf([X(:) Y(:)],[0 0]',sigma.*eye(2));
filter = reshape(filter,[rows,cols]);

% //convolution theorem
im_fft = fft2(im);
im_filt = ifft(im_fft.*repmat(filter,[1,1,bands]));

% //display
figure;subplot(1,2,1);imagesc(im);title('Original image');
subplot(1,2,2);imagesc(im_filt);title('Filtered Image');
```